# PHP's SPL: Do its interfaces involving arrays cover all array properties?

Tags: php, arrays, spl

Would it be possible to write a class that is virtually indistinguishable from an actual PHP array by implementing all the necessary SPL interfaces? Are they missing anything that would be critical?

I'd like to build a more advanced Array object, but I want to make sure I wouldn't break an existing app that uses arrays everywhere if I substituted them with a custom Array class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only problems i can think of are the gettype() and the is_array() functions.
Check your code for

```
gettype($FakeArray) == 'array' 
is_array($FakeArray)
```

Because although you can use the object just like an array, it will still be identified as an object.

Comment: Even then, it looks like I could use the override_function() function to override those functions to account for additional cases.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the points made above, you would not be able to make user-space array type hints work with instances of your class. For example:

```
<?php
function f(array $a) { /*...*/ }

$ao = new ArrayObject();
f($ao); //error
?>
```

Output:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to f() must be an array, object given
```

Answer (score 3):

Other differences include the '+' operator for arrays (merging) and the failure of the entire `array_*` functions, including the commonly used `array_merge` and `array_shift`.